# Passing Function Props in React-Typescript from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Type and trying to props from Parent to Child using Type-React,
Getting an error, that I already look but to no avail "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Function'."

Parent

```js
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./navbar";
import Main from "./main";

function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState("main");

  let pageView = null;
  switch (page) {
    case "main":
      pageView = <Main />;
      break;

    case "about":
      break;

    case "portfolio":
      break;

    default:
      pageView = <Main />;
      break;
  }

  const changePage = (page: string) => {
    setPage(page);
  };

  let nav = <Navbar pageView={pageView} changePage={changePage(page)}/>;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {nav}
      {pageView}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child

```js
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  pageView: any;
  changePage: Function
}

const navbar = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <nav className='navbar'>
      <ul className='navbar-nav'>
        <li className='nav-item' id='themeButton'>
          <a href='#' className='nav-link'>
            <span className='link-text'>Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className='nav-item' id='themeButton'>
          <a href='#' className='nav-link'>
            <span className='link-text'>Portofolio</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className='nav-item' id='themeButton'>
          <a href='#' className='nav-link'>
            <span className='link-text'>About</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default navbar;
```

So I want to props function changePage to the child, I usually do this on Javascript React, but typescript, and got confused, after looking around.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because, in the parent component you are not passing the function (changePage), you are passing its return value.

Change this

```
let nav = <Navbar pageView={pageView} changePage={changePage(page)}/>;
```

To

```
let nav = <Navbar pageView={pageView} changePage={changePage}/>;
```